# Visualstudio 2015 + Resharper GER keybindings ctrl + alt + 1to7 (angled bracket) not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, key-bindings

I am experiencing and odd keybinding behaviour after installing VisualStudio 2015 and Resharper on my Surface Pro 3 running Windows 8.1.

**Problem**

Usually ctrl + alt + 7 should type an "{" but it actually does nothing on any text input (VS, Notepad++, Editor).
All other GER typical bindings with ctrl + alt + 1 to 7 also do not work like they should.
ctrl + alt + 1 for example launches Firefox (which is first shortcut in my quicklaunch, but changing that does not launch another program).
The other combinations seem to do nothing...

**Odd Workaround**

If I perss ctrl+alt+ctrl+7 or altgr + ctrl + 7 I get my "{"!!!
This works for any other special character on 1 to 7 keys.

**Tested so far**

- First I thought my keyboardlayout may have been corrupted somehow but it is corretly set to "DEU". Just to make shure I switched to "ENG" deleted "GER", reinstalled "GER" and switched back, no impact.
- To make shure the keyboard driver works fine I installed PointerFocus and have verifed that pressing the alt or ctrl or altgr key on the board really calls the correct character.
- To check if my Surface Keyboard does any harm I activated the full onscreen keyboard of my Surface and ... clicking on AltGr + 7 which even displays "{" as the character to type it does nothing! So at least my keyboard seems to work fine and it must be a keybinding issue.
- I found the articles on Resharper to Override VisualStudio Keyboard bindings, but could not find any bindings to altgr + 7 overriding the "{"

So right now I have run out of ideas and hope someone might have a smile on his face thinking "Dude, you missed ..."

Cheers folks

Comment: Since the problem affects all programs I think that this is not the right place to ask. I'd suspect some program running in the background intercepting the keyboard events.

Comment: Hi Lucero, possibly yes. What I can add is that the keybindings worked after a fresh Windows setup. Which place do you mean to look for a solution?

Comment: I'd suggest https://superuser.com and ask a question about the keys not working in general, not specifically related to dev tools.

Comment: I'll try, cheers.