# Find shortcut in Visual Studio by used keys

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm still searching for a solution for this problem
[Keybindings in VS with Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014861/visualstudio-2015-resharper-ger-keybindings-ctrl-alt-1to7-angled-bracket). But since I had no luck jet I'd like to try another approach.

How can I find a shortcut by the used keys in Visual Studio and ReSharper?
I want to find what is associated to Ctrl+Alt+7.
Is there a practical way besides clicking through the hundreds of shortcut possibiliets in Visual Studio Tools>Options>Keyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press the shortcut in VS keyboard options and then click “Shortcut currently used by” dropdown, it will show possible command conflicts:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sergey, this works, thank you. Unfortunately my problem seems to be located somewhere else. If I press "AltGr + 9" for example it is shown correctly as "Ctrl + Alt + 9". If I press "AltGr" + anything from 1 to 9 no keystroke is recognized ... If I launch "PointerFocus" to check if the keystrokes are recognized I get the correct feedback with "Ctrl + Alt + 7" for example... This realy is anoying ...